# Looking-up the values of one worksheet in another worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

Basically, I could do this manually, but as the data is huge, it would take a lot of time. This is urgent, I am sure there should be any formulaic ways of doing it.

I have two worksheets in excel.

Worksheet 1.

```
Column-A       Column-B          
Device Names    Total numbers
Device A        19
Device B        81   
Device C        12
Device D        21
etc.            etc.
```

Worksheet 2.

```
Column-A        Column-B          
Device Names    Total numbers
Device D        
Device S           
Device Z        
Device S        
etc.
```

I need the formula which will look-up the Device names in Column-A/Worksheet 2 in ColumnA/Worksheet 1. If the device names in worksheet 2 and worksheet 1 match, the data in Column-B of worksheet-1 should be transferred to Column-B in worksheet-2.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a formula in the Number column on Sheet 2.

=LOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:B5)

Assuming A2 is the "Device D" cell, and Sheet!A2:B5 is the range of device/number values over on Sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the VLOOKUP function.  I tried this with just 4 records like in your example and seemed to work. You might have to tweak the lookup range:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A$1:B$4,2,FALSE)
```

The result:

```
Device D    21
Device S    #N/A
Device Z    #N/A
Device S    #N/A
```